# How to enable logging in Poem

Tags: logging, rust, rust-poem

I am using [poem-web](https://github.com/poem-web/poem), a rust library for building http based services but I have not been able to figure out how to enable logging so I can see why a POST endpoint is failing with Bad Request Error. It is due to deserialisation issue and not seeing the logs does not help.

Anyone knows how I can enable the logging? So when the handler function cannot deserialze the payload in a POST I can see the error in the logs?

This will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poem uses [`tracing`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/) for [logging](https://github.com/poem-web/poem/blob/0671f1db68f56ac846175673f23c532934a333a5/Cargo.toml#L34). You can use any [`tracing::Subscriber`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/trait.Subscriber.html) implementation to capture the log output generated by tracing. Probably the most used library for creating a `Subscriber` is [`tracing-subscriber`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/).

Here a basic example for creating a `Subscriber` with `tracing-subscriber` that logs all log messages created by Poem in a nice format to `stdout`:

```
fn main() {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_env_filter("poem=trace")
        .init();

    // here your other code
}
```

If you want to show all tracing messages generated in all libraries, not just Poem, you can set `.with_env_filter("trace")`, instead. See [this section](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/filter/struct.EnvFilter.html#directives) of how you can configure the `EnvFilter`. Note that you have to import `tracing-subscriber` with the `env-filter` feature flag enabled for this to work.

Comment: Interesting, it used to be 'around'. This is fairly confusing though as it doesn't attach to a specific service and is just a catch all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'around'. A [subscriber](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/#subscribers) is just some type that implements the [`tracing::Subscriber`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/trait.Subscriber.html) trait. Callsites of tracing events and spans can be [registered](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/trait.Subscriber.html#method.register_callsite) with it, so that the subscriber is only notified about certain events, i.e. only those from a certain library.

Comment: Yes, but how does this work on service level for example? If you wanted to log the start and endtime "ms" between calls.

Comment: The [callsites](https://docs.rs/tracing-core/0.1.32/tracing_core/callsite/index.html#registering-callsites) of both log messages (your start and end timings) are registered globally in the callsite registry. All active subscribers are informed about it and can decide whether they'd like to [record](https://docs.rs/tracing-core/0.1.32/tracing_core/callsite/index.html#performing-static-filtering) the messages generated by the callsite `always`, `sometimes` or `never`. Based on a subscriber's interest in a callsite, it either receives messages from it or doesn't.